# Given two sets of strings wherein the first set's parent element is a descendant of the second set's parent element, how do I get the second set?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get the "grab me" text in HTML using vanilla javascript? I have some thoughts below, but I am looking for a better way.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h1>H1 here</h1>
    grab me
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
let firstSetString = document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML;
let BothSetString = document.querySelector("div").innerText.replace("\n","")
let secondSetString = BothSetString.replace(firstSetString,"")
console.log(secondSetString)// returns grab me
```

Comment: @pilchard seems to be jquery. Im looking for just plain javascript. Will refer to the link if I will use jquery. Thank you.

Comment: There are multiple answers that are vanilla js that propose the same solution as the answer you accepted here. The accepted answer often isn't the best answer, especially for older questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div has 3 child nodes: a text node, an h1 node, and another text node. The last child node contains the text to grab:

```js
const div = document.body.querySelector("div");
const text = div.childNodes[div.childNodes.length - 1].textContent;
console.log(text.trim());
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>H1 here</h1>
  grab me
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use regular expression**

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");
const texts = div.innerHTML.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/);
console.log(texts[2].trim());
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>H1 here</h1>
    grab me
</div>
```

**Use childNodes to filter**

---

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");

for(let i = 0; i < div.childNodes.length; i++){
  const childNode = div.childNodes[i];
  if(isEmpty(childNode.nodeValue) && childNode.nodeName == '#text'){
    console.log(childNode.nodeValue.trim());
  }
}

function isEmpty(val){
  return val ? val.trim() : true;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>H1 here</h1>
    grab me
</div>
```